# How can I place multiple images on another image in WPF

Tags: wpf, image, adorner

how can I place a number of images on top of another image and have them scale/move together when changing the size of the window. For example I have a floor plan image on which I need to place a number of smaller images. This could be images representing furnitures. Also I would like to be able to use the adorner layer of the added images.